# Disable link inside infoWindow / Box on Google Maps API (V3) using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have an infoBox displayed on a map that is populated with a list of links (I have given these links the class '.mapLinks').

My goal is to use JQuery within the 'main page' (contained within the page where maps canvas div is located) to identify and disable the links and instead use them to reveal a div that is located on the 'main page'. My JQuery is as follows;

```
$('.mapLinks').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#divOnMainPage').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, what isn't working? Are the `.mapLinks` added dynamically? If they are, you will need to use `.delegate()`. Or `.on()` on a parent.

Comment: Yes the infoBox is populated with the '.mapLinks' dynamically.  I'll try '.delegate()'.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are added dynamically you will need to use `.delegate()`:

```
$(document).delegate('.mapLinks', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#divOnMainPage').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Or if you are using 1.7+ you can use the `.on()` syntax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mapLinks', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#divOnMainPage').addClass('hidden');
});
```

This will bind the event to a parent element (`document` in this case) and catch the bubble up of the event. Therefore you can add and remove `.mapLinks` dynamically and it will still work.

Comment: @chib Not a problem! Welcome to StackOverflow, make sure to accept the answer that solved your issue once it is resolved.